# MySQL query from an specific DATE and HOUR

Tags: mysql, sql

Having a table of events with separated columns, date and hour like:

```
|---------------------------------|
|date           |time             |
|2020-02-04     |11:54:22         |
|2020-01-31     |23:23:01         |
|---------------------------------|
```

How do I can make a query to have from an specific day (like 2020-01-31 at 12:00:00 to current time).

Comment: First things first, give it a try!

Comment: Try your "Maybe" question and if it doesn't work, come back here and post what you tried and we'll help from there.

Comment: Consider not separating date and time

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL, you could store both date and time information in one column of type DATETIME which takes the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss (2020-02-04 11:54:22).
In order to query records for a specific interval, you can make use of the MySQL BETWEEN operator as you suggest. For example to retrieve all records for 2020-02-04 from noon to midnight, you can run the query below:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `datetime_column_name` BETWEEN `2020-02-04 12:00:00` AND `2020-02-04 23:59:59`;
```

To retrieve all records for today, up to the current time, you can make use of the MySQL CURDATE() and NOW() functions as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `datetime_column_name` BETWEEN CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00') AND NOW();
```